# Sum within list prolog

Tags: prolog

I´m trying to get the sum + input list in prolog, but no success so far.

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], [N]):-
    sum(T, X),
    N is X + H.
```

Input

```
sum([1,2],L).
```

This results in

```
N = [3]
```

What I´m trying to achieve

```
N = [3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `sum(Xs,Ys)` should build the list `Ys = [Sum|Xs]`, where `Sum` is the sum of the items of the list `Xs`, you can do:

```
sum(Xs, [Sum|Xs]) :-
    sum_rec(Xs, Sum).

sum_rec([], 0).
sum_rec([X|Xs], Sum):-
    sum_rec(Xs, PartialSum),
    Sum is X + PartialSum.
```

A better approach is to use a **accumulator** to compute the sum of the items of list `Xs`:

```
better_sum(Xs, [Sum|Xs]) :-
    better_sum(Xs, 0, Sum).

better_sum([], Acc, Acc).
better_sum([X|Xs], Acc, Sum) :-
    NewAcc is Acc + X,
    better_sum(Xs, NewAcc, Sum).
```

Results:

```
?- sum([1,2], L).
L = [3, 1, 2].

?- better_sum([1,2], L).
L = [3, 1, 2].

?- sum([3,2,7,5], L).
L = [17, 3, 2, 7, 5].

?- better_sum([3,2,7,5], L).
L = [17, 3, 2, 7, 5].
```